# Using T in class definition

Tags: c#

I have the issue of having to read arrays from `JSON`, which can contain strings, integers or doubles. C# does not like mixed arrays, I gathered, in particular `T[]` would not work, as one line can contain a mix.

Would this be feasible?

```
class Entry {
   T value;
}
```

Elsewhere:

```
var Row = new Entry[10];
```

Would this allow a mixed array?
What would the constructor of Entry have to look like?

Comment: The only way to get a truly heterogeneous array is with `dynamic`

Comment: What about `object[]`?

Comment: Have a look on dynamic, ExpandoObject, or (old school) object if you are not already familiar with them.

Comment: `T` is for "generic type", however you still cannot mix different `T`s. Your `Entry` class would have to define that it allows generics - `class Entry<T>`. Your `var Row` would then also have to provide a value for `T` - essentially, any instantiation would have. This would limit you to e.g. `new Entry<int>[10]` or `new Entry<string>[10]` or, to get generic types, `new Entry<object>[10]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could look at creating an `Either`, inspired by functional languages.

An easy to import implementation:

https://github.com/mcintyre321/OneOf

I.e:

```
var row = new OneOf<double,int,string>[10]
```

Or you could implement your own and learn a bunch along the way:

https://blog.ploeh.dk/2022/05/09/an-either-monad/

Alternatively, the Newtonsoft has a JObject class that has some of the logic you might be after.